# Why can I connect to Clickhouse using DBeaver/JDBC but not HTTP?

Tags: http, curl, jdbc, clickhouse

I have no problem connecting to a Clickhouse database using DBeaver. My understanding is that DBeaver uses the JDBC driver to interact with databases. The connection details that I am using are similar to what's shown in the image below. 
[image: DBeaver connection details]

However, I need to use the HTTP interface to query this database so that I can query it programmatically. According to Clickhouse documentation the click-house server should be listening for HTTP on port 8123. When I try to connect to the Clickhouse database with the same connection parameters (with the exception of the connection url) using the curl request

```
curl --location --request GET 'http://host:8123/?user=username&password=password'
```

I receive the error

```
Code: 516, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: username: Authentication failed: password is incorrect or there is no user with such name (version 20.6.4.44 (official build))
```

**I think my question ultimately boils down to what is JDBC doing under the hood?** I assume it is using HTTP in some fashion since the JDBC URL uses port 8123. **But how can I replicate the JDBC connection using a basic CURL request?**

[Relevant Clickhouse Documentation](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/interfaces/http/)

Comment: JDBC doing nothing. It should work, check the password, try without password `curl 'http://host:8123/'` it should reply with `ok`,  then try `curl 'http://host:8123/?user=username&password=password&query=select+1'`